# WatchKit WKInterfaceMovie fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

let video = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "mp4")

@IBOutlet var videoShown: WKInterfaceMovie!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    videoShown.setMovieURL(video!)
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

}
```

My code is shown above, I am trying to play a video located in my assets folder of XCode on my WatchKit app using `WKInterfaceMovie` but I get this error when the app loads:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: I think your video url is nil and you are forcefully unwarpping that double check your video in nsbundle .

Comment: @Abhishek What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is the location of your video. Copy the file into "WatchKit Extension" folder, and not into the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

because, You are creating url for video.mp4 using

```
let video = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video", withExtension: "mp4")
```

But when you are trying to forcefully unwrap it in

```
videoShown.setMovieURL(video!)
```

system was not able to find the file video.mp4 in Watchkit Extension.

Check below image. [image: check image]

**1) Make sure that you have added video.mp4 file in watchkit extension as per first point in image**

**2) If you not added video.mp4 in watch, make sure checkbox for watchkit extension is selected for your video. This way you can add same file to multiple groups like iOS app as well as watch app without making multiple copies of same file.**